# C: Error de segmentación al eliminar Nodo de una Lista

Tags: c, array, punteros

Necesito que el programa elimine un nodo de la lista(doblemente ligada) cuando cierta condición ocurre, sin embargo cuando esto sucede, al intentar acceder a los valores anteriores y posteriores del nodo marca el error de:

> Segmentation Fault 11

Estuve probando el codigo y me di cuenta que este error se presenta justamente en la linea 114, en la funcion de borrar nodo:

```
void deleteNODO(LISTA* list,NODO*nod){
  printf("%s\n","eliminar nodo" );
  NODO* pointer = list->head;
    while (pointer!=NULL) {
      if (pointer == nod) {
        printf("%s\n","encontrado!");
        if (pointer == list->head) {
          printf("%s\n","lista vale 1" );
          list->head = pointer->next;
          list->tail = NULL;
        } else if (pointer == list->tail) {
          printf("%s\n","lista en cola" );
          list->tail =  pointer->prev;
          list->tail->next = NULL;
        } else{
          printf("%s\n","lista cuerpo" );

          NODO* previo = pointer->prev;
          printf("%s\n","1" );
          //PROBLEMA JUSTAMENTE AQUI
          previo->next = pointer->next;
          printf("%s\n","2" );
          pointer->next->prev = previo;
          printf("%s\n","3" );

        }
        list->size--;
        freeNodo(pointer);
      }
    }

}
```

y bueno si es necesario también dejo el resto del codigo:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "assert.h"

typedef struct{
  double *F; // vector n-dimensional
  int n; // dimension del vector F
} SOLUCION;

typedef struct nodo{
SOLUCION solucion;
  struct nodo *prev;
  struct nodo *next;
} NODO;

typedef struct{
  NODO *head;
  NODO *tail;
  int size;
} LISTA;
void cpySolucion(NODO*to , NODO*from){
  to->solucion.n = from->solucion.n;
  memcpy(to->solucion.F,from->solucion.F,sizeof(double)*to->solucion.n);

}
void initNodo(NODO* nod){
  int dim = nod->solucion.n;
  nod->solucion.F = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*dim);
  nod->next = NULL;
  nod->prev = NULL;
};
void freeNodo(NODO*nod){
  nod->next = NULL;
  nod->prev = NULL;
  free(nod->solucion.F);
  free(nod);
}
void cpyNodo(NODO* to, NODO* from){
  cpySolucion(to,from);
    to->next = from->next;
    to->prev = from->prev;
}

void addLista(LISTA* list, NODO* nodo){
  printf("%s\n","añadiendo a la lista" );
    NODO* newnodo;
    newnodo = (NODO*) malloc(sizeof(NODO));
  if (list->size == 0) {
    assert(list->head==NULL);
    assert(list->tail==NULL);
    initNodo(newnodo);
    cpyNodo(newnodo,nodo);
    list->head = newnodo;
    list->tail = newnodo;
    newnodo->next = NULL;
    newnodo->prev = NULL;
    list->size = list->size +1;
  } else {
    initNodo(newnodo);
    cpyNodo(newnodo,nodo);
    newnodo->prev = list->tail;
    list->tail = newnodo;
    newnodo->prev->next = newnodo;
    newnodo->next = NULL;
    list->size = list->size +1;
  }
}

NODO* getElementAtPosition(LISTA*list ,int pos){
  NODO* returnNodo = list->head;
  for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
    returnNodo = returnNodo->next;
  }
  return returnNodo;
}
void deleteElementAtPosition(LISTA* list,int pos){
  NODO* elemento = getElementAtPosition(list,pos);

    if (list->size == 1) {
      list->head = NULL;
      list->tail = NULL;
    } else if (elemento == list->tail) {
      list->tail =  elemento->prev;
      list->tail->next = NULL;
    } else{
      NODO* previo = elemento->prev;
      elemento->prev->next = elemento->next;
      elemento->next->prev = previo;
    }
    list->size--;
    freeNodo(getElementAtPosition(list,pos));
}
void deleteNODO(LISTA* list,NODO*nod){
  printf("%s\n","eliminar nodo" );
  NODO* pointer = list->head;
    while (pointer!=NULL) {
      if (pointer == nod) {
        printf("%s\n","encontrado!");
        if (pointer == list->head) {
          printf("%s\n","lista vale 1" );
          list->head = pointer->next;
          list->tail = NULL;
        } else if (pointer == list->tail) {
          printf("%s\n","lista en cola" );
          list->tail =  pointer->prev;
          list->tail->next = NULL;
        } else{
          printf("%s\n","lista cuerpo" );

          NODO* previo = pointer->prev;
          printf("%s\n","1" );
          //PROBLEMA JUSTAMENTE AQUI
          previo->next = pointer->next;
          printf("%s\n","2" );
          pointer->next->prev = previo;
          printf("%s\n","3" );

        }
        list->size--;
        freeNodo(pointer);
      }
    }

}
int vectoresSonIgules(NODO*nod1 , NODO*nod2){
  int sonIguales = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < nod1->solucion.n; i++) {
    if (nod1->solucion.F[i] != nod2->solucion.F[i]) {
      sonIguales = 0;
    }
  }
  return sonIguales;
}
int primerVectorEnNodoDominaSegundo(NODO*nod1,NODO*nod2){
  for (int i = 0; i < nod1->solucion.n; i++) {
    double currentNumber = nod1->solucion.F[i];
    for (int a = 0; a < nod1->solucion.n; a++) {
      if (currentNumber <= nod2->solucion.F[a]) {
        continue;
      } else{
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  int sonIguales = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < nod1->solucion.n; i++) {
    if (nod1->solucion.F[i] != nod2->solucion.F[i]) {
      sonIguales = 0;
    }
  }
  if (sonIguales == 1) {
    return 0;
  } else{
    return 1;
  }
}
void initLista(LISTA* list) {
  list->size = 0;
  list->head = NULL;
  list->tail = NULL;
}
void actualizaSolucion(LISTA*list,NODO* nod){
  printf("%s\n","Actualizando solucion");
  if (list->size==0) {
    printf("%s\n","lista 0");
    addLista(list,nod);
  } else{
    int numero = list->size;
    for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
      printf("%d\n",list->size);
      if (primerVectorEnNodoDominaSegundo(nod,getElementAtPosition(list,i)) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n","A DOMINA a B" );
        deleteNODO(list,getElementAtPosition(list,i));
      } else if (primerVectorEnNodoDominaSegundo(getElementAtPosition(list,i),nod) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n","B DOMINA a A" );
        return;
      } else if (vectoresSonIgules(nod,getElementAtPosition(list,i)) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n","son  igules" );
        return;
      }
    }
    addLista(list,nod);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  LISTA nuevaLista;
  initLista(&nuevaLista);
  int dimension;
  int cantidad;
  printf("%s\n","ingrese la cantidad de vectores");
  scanf("%d",&cantidad);
  printf("%s\n","ingrese la dimension" );
  scanf("%d",&dimension);

  double (*vectores)[dimension] = malloc(sizeof(double[cantidad][dimension]));
  int numero = 0;
  switch (dimension) {
    case 2:
      for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
          scanf("%lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1]);
          numero++;
        }
    break;
    case 3:
    for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1],&vectores[b][2]);
      }
    break;
    case 4:
    for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1],&vectores[b][2],&vectores[b][3]);
      }
    break;
    case 5:
    for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1],&vectores[b][2],&vectores[b][3],&vectores[b][4]);
      }
    break;
    case 8:
    for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1],&vectores[b][2],&vectores[b][3],&vectores[b][4],&vectores[b][5],&vectores[b][6],&vectores[b][7]);
      }
    break;
    case 10:
    for (int b = 0; b < cantidad; b++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf",&vectores[b][0],&vectores[b][1],&vectores[b][2],&vectores[b][3],&vectores[b][4],&vectores[b][5],&vectores[b][6],&vectores[b][7],&vectores[b][8],&vectores[b][9]);
      }
    break;
    default:
      printf("%s\n","POR FAVOR INGRESA UNA CANTIDAD VALIDA");
    }
    printf("%d\n",numero );

  for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    printf("%s %d\n","iteracion" ,i);
      NODO actualnodo;
      actualnodo.solucion.n = dimension;
      initNodo(&actualnodo);
      for (int a = 0; a < dimension; a++) {
        actualnodo.solucion.F[a] = vectores[i][a];
      }
      actualizaSolucion(&nuevaLista,&actualnodo);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nuevaLista.size; i++) {
      for (int a = 0; a < getElementAtPosition(&nuevaLista,i)->solucion.n; a++) {
        printf("%lf ",getElementAtPosition(&nuevaLista,i)->solucion.F[a]);
      }
      printf("%s\n","");

    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No tengo ahora tiempo de depurar tu código, pero te indico que si obtienes un segfault es por intentar acceder a datos de un puntero nulo (o un puntero que no apunta a una zona válida). Puesto que la línea que te da problemas es `previo->next = pointer->next;` la causa puede ser que o bien `pointer` o bien `previo` sean `NULL`. Creo que podemos descartar `pointer` pues justo antes habías accedido a `pointer->prev` sin problemas, por lo que yo verificaría bien que `previo` no sea `NULL`. Ya que previo es el valor de `pointer->prev` verifica cuando construyes la lista que le asignas algo válido.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla. Nos ayudará a todos para darte una solución más rápidamente.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo, compilador y versión de C estás utilizando? Esto nos ayudará a enfocar tu problema mucho más. También tienes páginas donde puedes compilar tu código online para que reproduzcamos tu problema mucho mejor.